# jQuery - set select index by elements id

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option id="sel01" value="some value">some value</option>
  <option id="sel02" value="some other value">some other value</option>
  <option id="sel03" value="maybe me">maybe me</option>
  <option id="sel04" value="and another one">and another one</option>
</select>
```

I would like to select an option with use of jQuery, but not by value:

```
$("#mySelect").val(1);
```

but by elements id.

Thanks for an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `prop` method.

```
var id = 'sel02';

$('#mySelect option').filter(function(){
   return this.id === id
}).prop('selected', true);
```

or:

```
$('#' + id).prop('selected', true);
```

Or if you want to select an option based on it's index, you can use `eq` method:

```
$('#mySelect option').eq(1).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   var id= "sel01";

    $('#selectid option').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == id){
           $(this).attr('selected',true);
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the element value using the ID and use the value for the jQuery `val()`.

```
var elementId = 'sel01';
$("#mySelect").val($('#' + elementId).val());
```

Comment: Love Your way, but "undefined" was first withh his method. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski It's up to you to pick which solution you like better :)

Comment: The best thing is the ability to learn all the ways and understand them :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the option:

```
$('#mySelect option#sel02').prop('selected',true);
```

if you want to get the selected option id's value:

```
$('#mySelect option#sel02').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax,

```
$('select option:selected').attr('id');
```

check [here](http://jsbin.com/olehod/1/edit), it will select the option based on the text value.

Answer (score 0):

Like this. Just change the number in eq(0)

```
$("#mySelect").val($("#mySelect").children().eq(0).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context but this worked for me when I needed to get data from json and make the option of that specific combo box selected:

```
$("#mySelect option[id='" + someVariable + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: oops, sorry about that :(